# How to add two arrays an convert it to csv?

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to add two arrays like:

```
A = [stu vtz , smkkn ,gfd , hskb , nsn ,ffdsf]
B = [abc ,def , ghi , jkl , mno , pqr ]
```

my desired out put in **CSV** is:

```
|    A   |   B  |
|--------|------|
|stu vtz |abc   |
|smkkn   |def   |
|gfd     |ghi   |
|hskb    |jkl   |
|nsn     |mno   |
|ffdsf   |pqr   |
```

Comment: Try using zip(A, B) and for looping over the return value

Comment: Do you want the `|` and `---` in the CSV file?

Comment: See how to create a [mcve].

Comment: @risheendra have you tried writing any code? SO should be a last resort after trying it yourself, not a first resort. If you're stuck, look into [writing a CSV](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), then work on getting the list data into a columwise format that can be written as you expect.

Comment: i dont want them peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need the CSV module. This code should work for you:

```py
A=['a','b','c','d','e','f']
B = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
import csv
with open('your-file.csv','w',newline='') as csvfile:
    writer=csv.writer(csvfile,dialect='excel')
    writer.writerow(['A','B'])
    writer.writerow(['-','-'])
    for a,b in zip(A[1:],B[1:]):
        writer.writerow([a,str(b)])
```

`zip()` allows you to iterate over two lists at the same time. `str()` is necessary to convert the integers in `B` to strings. Finally, `dialect='excel'` is optional but prevents excel from opening a warning dialog when you open the file with excel.